# Is it possible to change the predefind Bootstrap classes set in the application layout control in ExtLib

Tags: javascript, css, xml, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I am using the responsive Bootstrap theme together with the application layout control in extlib and cannot really find any documentation about if it is possible to change the Bootstrap predefined classes.

in the following example there is a titlebar with tabs using the predefined Bootstrap class "nav nav-tabs"
In my case I do not want the "[nav-tabs](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navs.php)" class, instead I want the "[nav-pills](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navs.php)" class but I find no way to change this using the source editor, I know I can change classes using client side script but I am hoping there is a server side way to control this.

[image]

```
<xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration legal="Copyright " placeBar="true" banner="true" fixedNavbar="fixed-bottom" footer="true" invertedNavbar="true" placeBarName="#{javascript:compositeData.Title}" rightColumnLabel="RightColumnLabel" titleBar="true" defaultNavigationPath="/tab1/link1" productLogo="/logo.gif" pageWidth="full">
            <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="page1" page="/page1.xsp"></xe:pageTreeNode>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="page2" page="/page2.xsp"></xe:pageTreeNode>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="page3" page="/page3.xsp"></xe:pageTreeNode>
            </xe:this.titleBarTabs>
        </xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
</xe:this.configuration>
```

I have tried to add a class like this but it does nothing to the html

```
<xe:this.titleBarTabs styleClass="nav nav-pills">
```

Comment: I suspect that this is handled by the renderer. Mark Leusink might know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular bootstrap CSS class is set in the `TitleBarTabsRenderer` of the com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap plugin. Check the source code [here](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap/src/com/ibm/xsp/theme/bootstrap/renderkit/html/extlib/layout/tree/TitleBarTabsRenderer.java). And that renderer is used by `ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer` to render the tabs.

As it is currently setup, your best bet to do what you want would be to use CSJS as you say, or to extend and override the `TitleBarTabsRenderer` and `ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer` classes. Not the simplest approach, so perhaps this could be turned into an SPR/enhancement request and looked at for a future extlib release.

Comment: I'd go with the CSJS approach for now: $(".applayout-titlebar-tabs").removeClass("nav-tabs").addClass("nav-pills");

Comment: Mark was faster than me and I can confirm that this works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can easily override the nav-tabs class set by the boostrap theme by creating my own theme, like so:

```
<theme extends="Bootstrap3.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd" >
<control>
    <name>TabbedPanel</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>nav nav-pills</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```